# How to use Forwarding Refs with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, use-ref, react-forwardref

I already understand the concept of Forwarding Refs and react-router-dom. But in this implementation, I'm not sure how to use it correctly.
I have a child component, where there is a function that set null in a useState.
I want this function to be executed every time I click on the menu item that renders this child component.
This menu is mounted in the com List and the Router in the App, as shown in the 3 files below.
Precisely, I don't know where to put the useRef to execute the child function resetMyState, if it's in App.js or or AppBarAndDrawer.js and how to do it.

childComponent.js

```
...
const MeusAnuncios = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(null);
   
  function resetMyState(){
     setMyState(null)
  }
  async function chargeMyState() {
      await
      ...
         setMyState(values)
      ...
   }
...
```

AppBarAndDrawer.js

```
...
const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {[
          { label: "Minha Conta", text: "minhaConta", icon: "person" },
          { label: "Novo Anúncio", text: "novoAnuncio", icon: "queue_play_next" },
          { label: "Meus Anúncios", text: "meusAnuncios", icon: "dvr" },
          { label: "Estatísticas", text: "estatisticas", icon: "line_style" },
          { label: "Faturamento", text: "faturamento", icon: "local_atm" },
          { label: "childComponent", text: "childComponent", icon: "notifications" },
        ].map(({ label, text, icon }, index) => (
          <ListItem
            component={RouterLink}
            selected={pathname === `/${text}`}
            to={`/${text}`}
            button
            key={text}
            disabled={text !=='minhaConta' && !cadCompleto ? true : false}
            onClick={() => {click(text) }}            
          >
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={label.toUpperCase()} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );

return(
...
   {drawer}
...
)
...
```

App.js

```
...
export default function App() {

  const childRef = useRef();
  ...
  <Router>           
    <AppBarAndDrawer/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/childComponent">
        <childComponent />
      </Route>
  ...
...
```

Comment: I even got the desired result, but in a strange way, on the click of the desired menu, I force the refresh on AppBarAndDrawer.js. 
But I want only myState to be null when I click on the desired menu option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ref` you create does need to reside in a common ancestor, i.e. `App`, so it and a callback can be passed on to children components. The `ref` to `ChildComponent` and the callback to the `AppBarAndDrawer`. Additionally, the `ChildComponent` will need to use the [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook to expose out the child's `resetMyState` handler.

MeusAnuncios

Use the `useImperativeHandle` hook to expose out the `resetMyState` handler.

```
const MeusAnuncios = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(null);
   
  function resetMyState(){
    setMyState(null);
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    resetMyState,
  }));

  async function chargeMyState() {
    await
    ...
    setMyState(values)
    ...
  }

  ...
});
```

App

Create a `resetChildState` callback and pass the ref to the child component and callback to the `AppBarAndDrawer` component.

```
export default function App() {
  const childRef = useRef();

  const resetChildState = () => {
    if (childRef.current.resetMyState) {
      childRef.current.resetMyState();
    }
  };

  ...

  <Router>           
    <AppBarAndDrawer onClick={resetChildState} /> // <-- pass callback
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/childComponent">
        <ChildComponent ref={childRef} /> // <-- pass ref
      </Route>
      ...
    </Switch>
    ...
  </Router>
}
```

AppBarAndDrawer

Consume and call the passed callback.

```
const AppBarAndDrawer = ({ onClick }) => { // <-- destructure callback
  ...

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      ...
      <List>
        {[
          ...
        ].map(({ label, text, icon }, index) => (
          <ListItem
            component={RouterLink}
            selected={pathname === `/${text}`}
            to={`/${text}`}
            button
            key={text}
            disabled={text !=='minhaConta' && !cadCompleto}
            onClick={() => {
              click(text);
              onClick(); // <-- call callback here
            }}            
          >
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={label.toUpperCase()} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      ...
    </div>
  );

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand the concept.
I made the adjustments as shown, but when clicking on the option, it returns an error that onClick is not a function.

The only difference in the code is when receiving in AppBarAndDrawer , where I already received props, I put onClick like this:

function ResponsiveDrawer(props,{ onClick }) {

Comment: using onClick with props.onClick, returns

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resetMyState')

Comment: It looks like resetMyState function is not available via ref exposed as
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        resetMyState,
    }));

Comment: @ViniciusSouza If `ResponsiveDrawer` is the component ultimately receiving the `onClick` callback and it's already using a defined `props` argument, then instead of `ResponsiveDrawer(props, { onClick }) {` use `ResponsiveDrawer(props) {` and in the code use `props.onClick()`. React components only have a single argument, the props object. I'll see about creating a running sandbox demo for you. In the meantime, can you share a more complete code example of all the components used? From `App` through to the drawer and the child component?

Comment: I will prepare a portion of this code to share.

Comment: Hello, @DrewReese I had some priorities changed, that's why the delay in posting part of the working code to verify the problem reported. https://github.com/vicius83/dashboardReactMenu https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-stonebraker-rptz1q

Comment: @ViniciusSouza Ok, I've cloned that repo into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-browser-b47xbr). Can you walk me through the UI and steps to reproduce the issue? Oops, looks like you added a sandbox after an edit I didn't see yet.

Comment: Click on the second option, "MEUS ANUNCIOS". He who will call the function by REF in App and by callback in AppAndDrawler. It will generate the error I mentioned before. That when clicking on this option, you should clear the state of the child component.

Comment: @ViniciusSouza Ok, thanks. Checked and reproduced the error.

Comment: @ViniciusSouza Ah you know what... I didn't really see that you are conditionally rendering the component you are attaching the ref to and the thing you are clicking on is navigating to that route. You can place the `childRef.current.resetMyState` in a `setTimeout` callback that places its processing to the end of the event queue which allows the navigation action to be processed and the `MeusAnuncios` component getting the ref to be mounted and available in the DOM. See this forked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-forwarding-refs-with-react-router-dom-3v4ush).